Regex pattern matching every url and not filtering
So I have the following urls from an app:
1.${endpoint}/list?currentPage=1&itemsPerPage=20&orderBy=name&orderType=1
2.${endpoint}/list?current=true&currentPage=1&itemsPerPage=20&orderBy=name&orderType=1
3.${endpoint}/list?currentPage=1&filter=current&itemsPerPage=20&orderBy=name&orderType=1&searchBy=
And the following Regex expression in React:
let endpointRegexString = `${endpoint.replace('*', '')}.*`;

if (filter) {
    endpointRegexString += `.*${urlPattern}.*`;
}

Where urlPattern is a prop that can be current, hub, lapsed, etc
My problem comes when trying to match the urls with urlPattern=current because I need to match the second and third urls without matching the first. But I'm matching the first because it's matching the currentPage part with current.
I have tried several patterns but I'm not able to solve the regex, thank you!
I tried several patterns like:
endpointRegexString += '(?!.*current.*currentPage)';

or:
endpointRegexString += `\\?.*currentPage=|&currentPage=`;

But I cannot match second and third urls without matching the first one

You can use word boundaries \bcurrent\b  see https://regex101.com/r/RQtWew/1

Surround the search terms with word boundaries \b, ie \bcurrent\b, \bhub\b, \blapsed\b.
This will prevent current matching currentPage, lapsed from matching elapsed, etc.
Word boundary \b matches between a word character \w and a non word character \W, or visa versa.
